# How can I get the height of a ListView item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have ListView and I need to determine item height.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [GetItemRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sahk6t.aspx) method:

```
int itemHeight = yourListView.GetItemRect(itemIndex).Height;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure but this might help:

```
int itemHeight = listView.Items[itemIndex].GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire).Height;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question however there is one issue - until the listview is drawn the values aren't set. And you may want to be able to set the sizes before you add any items (if for example I want to dry a listview that can display 5 entries but will start off empty).

Therefore my workaround was to run the following code, which forces the control to be rendered but without displaying it, in the application's initialisation section and save the values as global variables for later use. And, to get around listviews with different font sizes, to only store the difference between the height and the font height:

```
Dim lvwTemp As New ListView
lvwTemp.View = View.Details
lvwTemp.Columns.Add("test")
lvwTemp.Items.Add("test")
Dim zTempBitmap As New Bitmap(100, 100)
lvwTemp.DrawToBitmap(zTempBitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100))
zTempBitmap.Dispose()
gintListviewHeaderHeightMinusFontSize = lvwTemp.Items(0).GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire).Top - lvwTemp.Font.Height
gintListviewItemHeightMinusFontSize = lvwTemp.Items(0).GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire).Height - lvwTemp.Font.Height
```

Comment: This allows you to get column header height and item height very easily - nice!