# How do I get the Height of a ListViewItem in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is there any way to know the Height of a ListViewItem?

(I found it depended on the font size..)

Thanks,
Yehudit

Comment: Have you checked out the property `ListViewItem.Bounds.Height`?

Comment: I dont have such property... (maybe because I using Visual-Web-Gui)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem.aspx Every property you need.

Comment: See that- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706032/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-a-listview-item, but the solusion does not help me

Comment: @judian how did you know it didn't help? There are a few ways to get ListViewItem height but it seems that they all don't work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

int xh = ListView.GetItemRect(itemIndex).Height;